# Чем измерять скорость загрузки/генерации страниц?

Tags: плагин

Здравствуйте, чем посоветуете измерять скорость загрузки страницы, генерации и т.д.?

Answer (score 3):

Как бы ни ругали лису, хоть это скорее и не ее заслуга, но она имеет замечательный плагин firebug, профилирование там естественно есть. ИМХО firebug намного лучше и удобнее хромовских инструментов. Так же это плагин есть и в хроме, но функционал заметно ниже.

Answer (score 0):

В Хроме в инструментах разработчика есть необходимые средства. Плюс есть дополнение [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/speed/page-speed/docs/using_chrome.html). Если нужна общая статистика, то она собирается у Google в инструментах вебмастеров.